# Determine whether InnoDB plugin is installed in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do we check Innodb plugin is installed or not in MySQL?
Is there any variable to check Innodb Plugin is installed or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to determine whether or not InnoDB is enabled by querying the database, you should use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.

```
SELECT SUPPORT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ENGINES WHERE ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
```

Which, if InnoDB is enabled and is the default database, gives a result of

```
+---------+
| SUPPORT |
+---------+
| DEFAULT |
+---------+
```

If InnoDB is available, but not the default engine, the result will be `YES`. If it's not available, the result will obviously be `NO`.

Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-engines-table.html
and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html for reference.

When InnoDB is available, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables you mentioned in a comment are also available.

```
SHOW TABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA LIKE 'INNODB%';

+----------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_INFORMATION_SCHEMA (INNODB%) |
+----------------------------------------+
| INNODB_CMP_RESET                       |
| INNODB_TRX                             |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET                    |
| INNODB_LOCK_WAITS                      |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                          |
| INNODB_CMP                             |
| INNODB_LOCKS                           |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 8):

Type:

`SHOW ENGINES`

at a mysql prompt.

Innodb will show up like so:

```
Engine: InnoDB
Support: YES
Comment: Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys
```

Comment: I want to know innodb_plugin is installed or not, innodb_plugin will give the information about transactions in information schema tables. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-information-schema-transactions.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `SHOW ENGINES;`

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

Answer (score -1):

"`show plugins`" is available, but my server is using the built-in InnoDB engine and it still isn't clear whether it is the built-in or plugin version.

It seems the best way to check is to look at the `my.cnf` file. According to the install docs for the plugin, you have to specifically ignore the built-in version and enable the plugin:

```
[mysqld] 
ignore-builtin-innodb 
plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.so 
;innodb_trx=ha_innodb_plugin.so   
;innodb_locks=ha_innodb_plugin.so  
;innodb_lock_waits=ha_innodb_plugin.so  
;innodb_cmp=ha_innodb_plugin.so  
;innodb_cmp_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so  
;innodb_cmpmem=ha_innodb_plugin.so  
;innodb_cmpmem_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so
```

(The plugin-load option value as shown here is formatted on multiple lines for display purposes but should be written in my.cnf using a single line without spaces in the option value. On Windows, substitute `.dll` for each instance of the `.so` extension.)

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html

The plugin replaces the built-in InnoDB as of v5.5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-installation.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following query to check if the InnoDB storage is installed and enabled

SHOW PLUGINS;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).